# If I am not awaiting a Call, does it still execute?

Tags: c#, async-await

ok so I have a function

```
public async Task Foo(){
    await SomeOtherFunctionAsync();
    Bar();
}
```

Bar() can't be made async, it only removes an entry from a dictionary.

What is the best approach in this case?

- is the Bar() executed still if it is not awaited?
- should I use Task.FromResult or something like that?

Comment: Sure it can be made async. Anything can be async. Just type `await Task.Run(Bar)` and its async. However, make sure your dictionary is not modified at the same time. If so, look into using `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Comment: ad1: yes, ad2: no. Please do not use Task.Run(Bar) as this infers overhead for no gains.

Comment: To answer your questions. 1) Yes, Bar is still executed if not awaited. As it is not async and not awaited, it is executed on the caller thread. 2) Since your call contains one await statement, you do not need `Task.FromResult`.

Comment: I think you're making the common mistake of thinking that `await` is involved in *starting* something happening. It's not. You hand it something that is *already running* and its job is to wait for that thing to finish.

Comment: To add to @Damien_The_Unbeliever point, think of every await-statement as [Current Calling Thread says to Task Scheduler]: "Here. Please find some Thread to run this job while I do something else in the meantime. Please let me know when it is finished so I can resume what I needed to do after this job. Thanks!"

Comment: I think helpful would be to explain what your function is doing.
You've made an async method that returns a Task. 
When it is called, it first calls `SomeOtherFunctionAsync()`.
This function returns a `Task` object, which is then handled by `await`.
`await` checks whether the `Task` is already completed (would be so if the method runs through synchronously), and if not then it returns a task itself at this point.
After the `Task` returned by `SomeOtherFunctionAsync()` has completed and the thread is was running from is free again, it continues in this method where it has stopped.

Comment: So long story short `Bar()` is executed after `SomeOtherFunctionAsync()` has completed.
If you want to run bar even if `SomeOtherFunctionAsync()` is not done yet you could do:
`Task t = SomeOtherFunctionAsync();
Bar();
await t;`

Comment: *"is the `Bar()` executed still if it is not awaited?"* -- Is your impression that every single line of code inside an `async` method must start with the `await` operator, otherwise the compiler just ignores it?

Answer (score 4):

One great thing about programming is that it very often is very easy to try.

```
await Foo();

async Task Foo(){
    await SomeOtherFunctionAsync();
    Bar();
}

async Task SomeOtherFunctionAsync() {
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
}

void Bar() {
    Console.WriteLine("Hello from Bar");
}
```

This prints `Hello from Bar` which shows `Bar()` is called.